# Python Pandas: Using Aggregate vs Apply to define new columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like so:

```
n = 20
dim1 = np.random.randint(1, 3, size=n)
dim2 = np.random.randint(3, 5, size=n)
data1 = np.random.randint(10, 20, size=n)
data2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': dim1, 'b': dim2 ,'val1': data1, 'val2': data2})
```

If I define a function that returns group-wise:

```
def h(x):
    if x['val2'].sum() == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x['val1'].sum())*1.0/x['val2'].sum()*1.0
```

Grouping by one of the columns and aggregating returns a result:

```
df.groupby(['a']).aggregate(h)['val1']
```

Albeit it converts all the existing columns to the desired result rather than adding a new column

Grouping by two columns leads to an error when using aggregate:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).aggregate(h)['val1']

KeyError: 'val2'
```

But switching aggregate for apply seems to work.

I have two questions:

1. Why does apply work and not aggregte?
2. If after grouping a dataframe by some set of keys, I want to use a function that aggregates group values as a new column, what's the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question. Actually, if you define some test function like `def test(x): print x; return x.sum()` and call `aggregate` in both cases, you'll see that in first case `x` is a DataFrame and in second case `x` is a Series (and when you call `apply`, it's always DataFrame). I don't have time to dig into the code at the moment, and I'm sure some pandas developers will show up and explain this behaviour :)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in 2. (perhaps it's [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items)?)

Comment: I have struggled to work out what is going on exactly with these groupby operations. As Roman points out, the first argument passed to agg is a series, therefore if you want to agg based on values in multiple columns you have to call the second column in the function based upon the index values of the series that is passed automatically. apply always passes as data frame as he points out. If you want to see some really strange behaviour check out transform, it seems to pass series and dataframes as the first argument to the function. Quite confusing IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To step back slightly, a faster way to do this particular "aggregation" is to just use [sum (it's optimised in cython)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) a couple of times.

```
In [11]: %timeit g.apply(h)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit g['val1'].sum() / g['val2'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 600 µs per loop
```

IMO The groupby code is pretty hairy, and usually lazily "blackbox" peek at what's going on, by creating a list of what values it's seeing:

```
def h1(x):
   a.append(x)
   return h(x)
a = []
```

*Warning: sometimes the type of data in this list is not consistent (where **pandas tries a few different things** before doing whatever calculation)... as in this example!*

The second aggregation gets stuck applying on *each* column, so the group (which raises an error):

```
0     10
4     16
8     13
9     17
17    17
19    11
Name: val1, dtype: int64
```

*This is subSeries of the val1 column where (a, b) =  (1, 3).*

This may well be a bug, after this raises perhaps it could try something else (my suspicion is that this is why the firsts version works, it's special cased to)...

For those interested the `a` I get is:

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]: 
[SNDArray([125755456, 131767536,        13,        17,        17,        11]),
 Series([], name: val1, dtype: int64),
 0     10
4     16
8     13
9     17
17    17
19    11
Name: val1, dtype: int64]
```

*I've no idea what the SNDArray is all about...*